# How to check winner in tic-tac-toe game using a matrix?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, function, 2d

Using a matrix, I need to check if someone wins in a tic-tac-toe game.

For example, 1 is for X, and -1 is for O:

```
[ 1, 0, 0]
[-1, 1, 0]
[-1,-1, 1]
```

the X user wins here.

How can I create a function that checks every element of the matrix?

```
dim matriceDuJeu(2,2) as Integer
'...
Function verifierSiJoueurGagne(valeur As Integer) As Boolean
    For i = 0 To 1
        For j = 0 To 1
            If matriceDuJeu(i, j) <> matriceDuJeu(i + 1, j) Or matriceDuJeu(i, j) <> matriceDuJeu(i, j + 1) Or matriceDuJeu(i, j) <> matriceDuJeu(i + 1, j + 1) Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: There's no magic solution. It's just logic. What logic would you use if you were doing it manually? That's the same logic you would use to do it in code. It's up to you to determine that logic first, then write code to explicitly implement that logic. If you can't explain that logic to us, it's too soon to be writing code at all. If you can explain that logic, explain it and show us how you've tried to implement it and tell us exactly how and where your implementation doesn't satisfy the requirement.

Comment: One way: if the sum of a row is 3 or -3 then someone has won. The same for the columns and diagonals.